# Adding Cloudflare IPs to AWS Security Group through CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Cloudflare provides all their IPs via https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4. Is there a way we can create a security group on AWS to allow all these without hardcoding each one of them in the CloudFormation script?
Maybe through a parameter or something similar.

Someone tried it through aws cli: https://gist.github.com/dduvnjak/a0bf8032222fe2b4b30cbcc599c241f0

Comment: Are you creating an instance as part of your template?

Comment: I am attaching a Security Group to a Fargate Service.

Comment: I would say there is no really smooth way to do this. But It could be done by creating a CF macro. CF macro is more less a Lambda function taking your CF and modify it as you tell the function to do. So in this way it should be possible but it will take a lot of work.

Comment: I don't wanna go that route or any that edits the template itself.